# Как сделать единую версию для всех проектов решения

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, assembly

Есть решение, в нем несколько проектов.
Например, проекты: *осн. прилож., сервис прилож., библиотека1, библиотека2.*
У каждого проекта своя версия, свой файл `assembly.cs`.
Как сделать файл общим, или версию общую?

Видел вариант, когда у основного проекта файл, а у остальных файла физически нет, но в дереве проектов есть и значок типа ярлыка.

Как это сделать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/4264/assemblyinfo-cs-examples/15029/global-and-local-assemblyinfo#t=201609220425104024345

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Очень просто.

Заведите в общем для всех проектов месте файл `CommonAssemblyInfo.cs`, в котором укажите общую для всех проектов информацию (например, версию).

Для каждого из проектов, который должен это использовать, удалите эту самую информацию из `AssemblyInfo.cs` (этот файл обычно находится в каталоге `Properties` в стандартном проекте). Добавьте `CommonAssemblyInfo.cs` в проект через Solution explorer → проект → Add... → Existing Item → `CommonAssemblyInfo.cs`, не забудьте выбрать «Add as link»

[image: Add as link]

Переместите добавленную ссылку в каталог `Properties` внутри проекта.

Для ваших целей в `CommonAssemblyInfo.cs` имеет смысл указать

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("10.1.0.0")]               
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("10.1.0.0")]           // File version в свойствах DLL
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("10.1.0.0")]  // Product version в свойствах DLL
```

Answer (score 13):

Создайте новый cs файл с

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.4")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3.4")]
```

и добавьте его во вcе проекты через "Add Existing Item" - "Add As Link".